# Webpack 5 Builds for AWS Lambda with TypeScript - Runtime.HandlerNotFound

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, webpack-5

I have deployed an AWS Lambda function using `Node.js 18` as the runtime and configured the handler as `bundle.handler`. The code is written in TypeScript and compiled with `Webpack 5`.
However, upon testing the function in the AWS console, I got the following error:

```
"errorType": "Runtime.HandlerNotFound",
"errorMessage": "bundle.handler is undefined or not exported"
```

**webpack.config.ts**

```
import { Configuration } from "webpack";
import { resolve } from "path";

const config: Configuration = {
  name: "bundle",
  mode: "none",
  entry: {
    bundle: "./src/main.ts",
  },
  target: "node",
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "ts-loader",
          options: {
            configFile: "tsconfig.json",
          },
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    modules: ["node_modules"],
    extensions: [".tsx", ".ts", ".js", ".json"],
    alias: {
      "@": resolve(__dirname, "../code/src"),
    },
  },
  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
    globalObject: "this",
    library: {
      name: "bundle",
      type: "commonjs2",
    },
  },
};

export default config;
```

**main.ts** fragment

```
export const handler: Handler = async (event, context): Promise<any> => {
  ...
  return context.logStreamName;
};
```

**bundle.js** fragment

```
const handler = (event, context) => __awaiter(void 0, void 0, void 0, function* () {
    ...
    return context.logStreamName;
});
exports.handler = handler;

...

/******/    // module cache are used so entry inlining is disabled
/******/    // startup
/******/    // Load entry module and return exports
/******/    var __webpack_exports__ = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = 0);
/******/    module.exports.bundle = __webpack_exports__;
```

**Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated!**

Comment: Do you need `library.name` in the webpack config? You should remove that otherwise your handler is exported as `bundle.bundle.handler` I think.

Comment: @morganney removing the `library.name` cause the same error

Comment: Actually, @morganney **you were right**, that did the trick.

Comment: @morganney Submit your answer and I'll be happy to accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using webpack's `output.library.type` with a value of [`commonjs`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#type-commonjs) the built library is exposed to consumers as such:

> The **return value of your entry point** will be assigned to the exports object using the `output.library.name` value. As the name implies, this is used in CommonJS environments.
>
> ```js
> exports['MyLibrary'] = _entry_return_;
>
> require('MyLibrary').doSomething();
> ```

You are running into issues because you are also using an object for `entry` which produces chunks [named](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/entry-context/#naming) after their associated keys, in this case `bundle`, **the same name used for your library**.

According to the [AWS docs for a lambda handler function in Node.js](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html)

> When you configure a function, the value of the handler setting is the **file name** and the **name of the exported handler method**, separated by a dot.

So when the lambda runtime attempts to load your handler it will call the bundle file name (`bundle`) and the name of your handler (`handler`), separated by a dot: `bundle.handler`. But your library build is named `bundle`, so your handler will be exposed as function of that namespace: `bundle.bundle.handler`.

**An easy solution with your current configuration would be to not use the `output.library.name`** and let your named entry export of `handler` be directly attached to the `exports` object under no namespace. There is a warning when in the webpack docs when not using `output.library.name`:

> Note that not setting a `output.library.name` will cause all properties returned by the entry point to be assigned to the given object; there are no checks against existing property names.

Thanks for the warning, noted, but in this case the runtime expects the exports to be directly attached based on the name already given to your bundle, and naming collisions are not anticipated, so removing the library name is acceptable.

There are other ways to produce a webpack build that is supported by the AWS lambda runtime, and uses `output.library.name`. In those other cases you most likely would not also use an object for your `entry`, but rather a string or array of strings, and then explicitly set `output.filename` to your library's name.

Comment: Awesome answer, pretty sure I was never going to work this out. Did this change somehow in webpack 4 -> 5? I've been updating some old code, so there are a lot of possible causes, but that one seems likely.

Comment: Looks like webpack 4 uses `output.libraryTarget` to define how to expose your lib to consumers, whereas webpack 5 uses `output.library.type` while still supporting `libraryTarget`, albeit with a deprecation warning.  The name for your lib is derived from `output.library` instead of `output.library.name`. Check out the corresponding v4 docs: https://v4.webpack.js.org/configuration/output/#expose-via-object-assignment